# Using Threads with Google Places API

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to use Google Places API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/

I am Implementing in Java with multiple threads. The idea is to fetch multiple POI(Point of interests : Pharmacy, School, Parks etc ) around a given address. So, I am using for example 52 threads to fetch 52 POIs at the same time for a given address in parallel .

My questions is : Is it against the Google policy or will it be considered intrusion by Google, since there is nothing in the documentation that I could find against it. ??

I am trying to develop a long term use application, which I do not want to be abandoned because of usage of Multi-threading.

Thank you

~ Nav

Answer (score 0):

The only restriction I know of is that you cannot send more than 1000 requests over 24 hours  with the same API key (unless you pay), but using multithreading or not to send the requests won't make any difference.